# Find all ul elements within a specific div that have more then 6 children? (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, attributes, html-lists, css-selectors

How do I find all the ul elements within a particular div that have greater than 6 li children and add an attribute of the UL element (i.e. data-theme="d")

```
<div id="dicCntr">
    <ul id="ul1">
        <li id="li1">A</li>
        <li id="li2">A</li>
        <li id="li3">A</li>
        <li id="li4">A</li>
        <li id="li5">A</li>
        <li id="li6">A</li>
        <li id="li7">A</li>
        <li id="li8">A</li>
        <li id="li9">A</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul2">
        <li id="li10">B</li>
        <li id="li11">B</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul3">
        <li id="li12">C</li>
        <li id="li13">C</li>
        <li id="li14">C</li>
        <li id="li15">C</li>
        <li id="li16">C</li>
        <li id="li17">C</li>
        <li id="li18">C</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul4">
        <li id="li19">D</li>
        <li id="li20">D</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#dicCntr ul').filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).children().length > 6;
    }).attr('data-theme', 'd');
```

Comment: This is the right idea except that `.data('theme', 'd')` doesn't actually add an attribute to the item if that's what the OP actually needs.  It only adds an entry in the jQuery-specific `data` dictionary which is a jQuery private data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question said specifically jquery but why not regular javascript

```
 var ulHolder = document.getElementById('dicCntr')
uls = ulHolder.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (i=0; i<uls.length; i++) {
    if (uls[i].children.length > 6) {
        uls[i].setAttribute('data-theme', 'd')      
    }
}
```